# gulp src vs webpack entry

Tags: gulp, webpack

I have the following  simple webpack  config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "entry.js",
    failOnError: true,
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "souce-map.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: ["./app"]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

and want to creat gulp  task that will run  webpack bundling and in future do some other stuff besides.

Here is the  article: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webpack I'm loooking  at. It tells that I can pass webpack  config like that:

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');

 gulp.task('default', function() {
   return gulp.src('??')
     .pipe(webpack(require('webpack.config.js')))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('??'));
 });
```

So the question is: I have already told in webpack config which file to  use as an  entry point and where to put the result. How does gulp.src and gulp.dest fits here? Shall I put the same files as for entry and output in webpack. It might be that I'm missing some  keypoint that's why it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define entry point with `gulp.src` and omit that in webpack config.

For the `gulp.dest` use just destination folder path.

e.g.

```js
 gulp.task('default', function() {
   return gulp.src('./entry.js')
     .pipe(webpack(require('webpack.config.js')))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
 });
```

Good luck!